# How do I move / install Homebrew onto my Mac user account? Another user set it up

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I have a Mac on Mavericks that was set up by a different user.

He set up Homebrew under his account, but when I type `brew` on my login I get

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- extend/module (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

### What I would like to achieve

1. get brew working on my login. (I do have admin rights and I also can login as the other user as needed)
2. Upgrade to Yosemite with me as the main user rather than him, but reinstall homebrew with most if not all of his casks
3. There is a lot of code on this development Mac, and configurations, so I don't want to just blow it all away.

`brew list > casts.txt` works fine, so long as I am logged in as the other user, so at least I know what is installed

Answer (score 0):

Brew is still not happy with my login, but the simple answer is to load El Capitan onto a separate boot disk and get brew working there, and then transfer the apps and files.  I'll still have access to the old drive, and can even boot it up if needed.

Answer (score 0):

## Q. How do I move / install Homebrew onto my Mac user account?

## A.  Looks like an issue with version incompatibilities or permissions.

First I would be sure the mac is as up to date as possible.

Looks alot like a ruby issue as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652996/homebrew-not-working-on-osx

If hombrew is properly working, you should be able to change the permissions as explained here:

[Enable multiple users to install software using homebrew](https://superuser.com/questions/283254/enable-multiple-users-to-install-software-using-homebrew)

Also check the homebrew troubleshooting guide:

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md

If it is not working properly the simpler solution would probably be to re-install homebrew and install all the elements you know you need.  Very often, if you have a dependency missing, homebrew will tell you.  The added benefit is that you are in control of what is installed.

The FAQ has the uninstall info.
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md

Comment: I'm on it! The new SSD hasn't arrived, so will try to sort this on the current Mavericks machine